# Recommended MaxPoolSize and maxIoThreads options for async/await action methods in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, async-await

In our ASP.NET application all methods use `async/await` keywords to improve IO performance.
However, I would like to now, what is the recommend connection pool size and `maxIoThreads` option per CPU core when using asynchronuous action methods. The default value for `maxIoThreads` is 20 and 100 for connection pool. It's also unclear, is the both options define the limit only for running threads or for all executing code in 'awaited' state.

Comment: The `ThreadPool` options define the limit of `ThreadPool` threads, exactly as their name suggests, certainly not the number of `async` methods executing, or anything like that.

Answer (score 3):

On ASP.NET, `async` and `await` actually *reduce* the number of thread pool threads in use. This is true unless you've implemented something improperly (e.g., using `Task.Run`).

As of .NET 4.5, the default ASP.NET settings are correct for asynchronous servers. The only recommended changes are:

1. Increase the IIS HTTP.SYS queue limit from 1000 to 5000.
2. (Only if your asynchronous requests are dependent on other HTTP/network requests) Increase `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` from its default of (12 times the number of cores).